# JsonResult not returned even after OnResultExecuted called successfully

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a 'Session-Less' Controller with an action that returns JsonResult. My client side Javascript uses Jquery ajax to call this action via HTTP GET

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Index()
{
    .... 
    // myResult has three properties of type bool, int and a string

    var jsonResult = Json(myResult, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    return jsonResult;
}
```

This code gets executed and I have verified that `OnResultExecuted` is called without any exception.

Client side JS

```
xhrNotification = $.ajax({
            url: '/MyController/', // default action
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            success: function (n, timeout, message) {

            },
            error: function (data) {

            }
        });
```

But the jsonResult only occasionally gets to the client side. I have been observing the request/response using Fiddler. The HTTP request has no response even after my action is executed. I am developing this under Visual Studio 2010.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** On further debugging I found an exception is raised after my Action is executed

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred
  Message=An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
  Source=System
  ErrorCode=10053
  NativeErrorCode=10053
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
```

Partial stack trace is as below

```
System.dll!System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags socketFlags) + 0x5a bytes 
    WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection.WriteBody(byte[] data, int offset, int length) + 0x40 bytes  
    [Appdomain Transition]  
>   WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.FlushResponse(bool finalFlush) + 0x128 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(bool finalFlush) + 0x4cb bytes 
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequest(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context, System.Exception e) + 0x80 bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.OnHandlerCompletion(System.IAsyncResult ar) + 0xa6 bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpAsyncResult.Complete(bool synchronous, object result, System.Exception error, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus status) + 0x3e bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x25e bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ResumeStepsFromThreadPoolThread(System.Exception error) + 0x28 bytes  
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(System.IAsyncResult ar) + 0x183 bytes   
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncUtil.WrapCallbackForSynchronizedExecution.AnonymousMethod__1() + 0x14 bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.SynchronizationContextUtil.Sync.AnonymousMethod__3() + 0x16 bytes   
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.SynchronizationContextUtil.Sync<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.AnonymousMethod__0(object o) + 0x32 bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback callback, object state) + 0x4a bytes   
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback callback, object state) + 0x5f bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.AspNetSynchronizationContext.Send(System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback callback, object state) + 0x9 bytes 
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.SynchronizationContextUtil.Sync<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext, System.Func<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid> func) + 0x58 bytes 
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.SynchronizationContextUtil.Sync(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext, System.Action action) + 0x46 bytes 
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncUtil.WrapCallbackForSynchronizedExecution.AnonymousMethod__0(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 0x6f bytes 
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.ExecuteAsynchronousCallback(bool timedOut) + 0x37 bytes   
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.HandleAsynchronousCompletion(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 0x1e bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.ExecuteAsynchronousCallback(bool timedOut) + 0x37 bytes   
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.HandleAsynchronousCompletion(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 0x1e bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.ExecuteAsynchronousCallback(bool timedOut) + 0x37 bytes   
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.HandleAsynchronousCompletion(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 0x1e bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<bool>.ExecuteAsynchronousCallback(bool timedOut) + 0x37 bytes 
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<bool>.HandleAsynchronousCompletion(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) + 0x1e bytes
```

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Updated my post with the Jquery Ajax code.

Comment: @b1naryj. nope, he has to allow get. `return Json(myResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong so far... What happens if request fails? Does client get at least an error message?

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev thanks. No, in Fiddler the request would never seem to receive a response. But occasionally it would work. I spent quite a while trying to resolve this before asking a question on SO. This problem is now resolved. Please see my answer. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev Unfortunately this is not resolved. I have added the exception and stacktrace now to the question. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: the stack trace seems to indicate a spotty connection...  perhaps an issue with your dev environment setup and not the posted code?

Comment: @DmactheDestroyer I was wondering if it could be Firewall/Antivirus fiddling with the socket... I am looking in to this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this call and see what happens: (might want to make sure you set type to 'GET', not 'get')

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '/MyController/',
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function(e) {
        },
        complete: function () {

        }
    });
```

Also, you may just want to do this in your controller:

```
return Json(myResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```